# What does the ~ symbol, placed above a vector, mean

Tags: notation, vector-analysis

On the wikipedia page for the [Poynting Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector), under the section 'time averaged Poynting vector', the ~ symbol is used above some of the vectors.  What does this mean?

Thank you.

Comment: I've seen overlines used for averages and overtildes (what you have) used for Fourier transforms before. I'm not interested in becoming familiar enough with Poynting vectors to try to answer this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen that decoration given any standardized meaning.

Based on the text description and how it's actually used there, I believe the following is what is meant.

The (time-varying) vector $\mathbf{E}$ is assumed to be sinusoidal function of $t$ -- it is a common trick to replace sinusoidal waves with complex exponentials: e.g.

$$ \cos x = \mathop{\text{Re}} \left( e^{ix} \right)$$
$$ \sin x = \mathop{\text{Im}}\left(e^{ix}\right) = \mathop{\text{Re}}\left( -i e^{ix} \right)$$

The (time-varying) vector $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}$ appears to be defined, along with the constant (with respect to time), complex vector $\mathbf{E}_c$ and real number $\omega$, by the two properties:

- $\mathbf{E} = \text{Re}(\tilde{\mathbf{E}})$
- $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{E}_c e^{i \omega t}$

Answer (score 0):

It usually stands for unit vector:

$$\tilde{v} = \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}.$$

The Poynting vector is a very useful concept in electromagnetism and it's usually denoted by $\vec{S}$.

Cheers!

Comment: Usually $\hat v$, not $\tilde v$ is used for that. And that doesn't look like what's being used on the linked wikipedia page.

Comment: You're right Hurkyl. I confused myself... Please, @user2646276, pay attention to Hurkyl's comment. Cheers!