# Meaning of tilde over a vector in Fourier analysis?

Tags: notation, fourier-analysis

A comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642556/what-does-the-symbol-placed-above-a-vector-mean) says "I've seen ... overtildes ... used for Fourier transforms before."  That question is about a different context, as is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678534/whats-the-meaning-of-tildey).

Discrete Fourier transforms do play a big role in the piece I'm reading, which includes expressions such as $\tilde{x}$, where $x$ is a vector.   (Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to cite or quote the work in question, so I don't want to provide detailed context.)

Is $\tilde{x}$ a common notation for a Fourier transform, as the quotation above implies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not really, no, the most common notation for the Fourier Transform (be it discrete or not) of a function $f$ (let's say $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$) is $\hat{f} = \mathcal{F}(f).$ Also the dummy variable for the argument of a Fourier transform is $\xi,$ whereas $x$ is kept as a dummy variable for the original function- for example we would write $\hat{f}(\xi) = \mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)$ and $f(x).$ I guess these are only notations that have been widely used over the years, so they became more or less standard nowadays. The tilde notation I have never encountered, but every author has their preferred way of denoting it, I guess. :)

Comment: Thanks Actually Fritz.  This is helpful.  In this case, the authors don't define this notation.  Either they forgot to do that, or it's a common conventional notation for something in their primary area of research (which is not mine).  I just noticed that Math.SE suggested [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579986/showing-hat-tildef-tilde-hatf-where-hatf-is-the-fourier-transfo?rq=1) as relevant; it includes a tilde in a Fourier analysis context, but I don't see why that would be appropriate in the work I'm reading.

Comment: I now think that the tilde has nothing to do with Fourier analysis per se, but is simply a notation for a possible statistical estimate, as suggested in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24935/notation-of-estimators-tilde-vs-hat) on Stats.SE.  (I was familiar with hat but not tilde as a notation indicating an estimate.)

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed, the most common notation for an estimator of $X$ is $\tilde{X}.$ However, this is an interesting thing as well, strictly notation-wise speaking. The reason I am saying this is because in a fairly large number of texts, the way an estimator is denoted depends on the method used in obtaining it.